# How to split SpaCy dependency tree into subclauses?

Tags: python, graph, tree, nlp, spacy

I am trying to split units of text by their dependency trees (according to SpaCy). I have experimented with much of the docs provided by spacy, but I cannot figure out how to accomplish this task. To visualize, see below:

```
import spacy
from spacy import displacy

doc = nlp('I was, I dont remember. Do you want to go home?')
dependency_flow = displacy.render(doc, style='dep', jupyter = True, options = {'disxatance': 120})
```

The code above results in this dependency tree graph (which is split into 2 screenshots due to size):

[image]

[image]

Intuitively, this indicates that there are 2 independent clauses in the original sentence. The original sentence was `'I was, I dont remember. Do you want to go home?'`, and it is effectively split into two clauses, `'I was, I dont remember.'`, and `'Do you want to go home?'`.

#### Output

**How, using SpaCy or any other tool, can I split the original utterance into those two clauses, so that the output is:**

`['I was, I dont remember.', 'Do you want to go home?']`?

My current approach is rather lengthy and expensive. It involves finding the two biggest subtrees in the original text whose relative indices span the range of the original text indices, but I'm sure there is another, better way.

Comment: Can a clause span multiple sentences?

Comment: The question is unclear to me. The example is quite obfuscating, because it does not contain any subclause. Would you like to get "I don't know who you are." split into ["I don't know", "who you are"]? This would be, what the term _subclause_ refers to normally. Or do you just mean _sentence_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your input and output, i.e. a clause does not span multiple sentences. Then, instead of going down the dependency tree rabbit hole, it would be better to get the clauses as sentences(internally they are spans) from the doc.

```py
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp('I was, I dont remember. Do you want to go home?')
print([sent.text for sent in doc.sents])
```

**Output**

```
['I was, I dont remember.', 'Do you want to go home?']
```

Comment: This works on the example of the OP, but fails on simple subclauses such as: _I don't know who you are._